# Disable a button once clicked in Angular2

Tags: html, typescript, angular

I have a silly problem but i didn't know how to overcome it since i'm using `Angular2` (`Typescript`) stuffs not `JavaScript`'s tools. I have this HTML code

```
<div  class=" uk-align-center" >
 <a class="md-btn md-btn-success" >Start</a>
<!--<a class="md-btn disabled" *ngIf="">Start</a>-->
</div>
```

Simply , I want to change the button status to `disabled` once clicked, I found Javascript ways but none of them worked for me, any Help please ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use following approach without touching your component,

```
<a class="md-btn md-btn-success"
   [class.disabled]="isClickedOnce"
   (click)="isClickedOnce = true">Start</a>
```

Answer (score 14):

another solution with code side:

```
<button name="submitButton" #submitButton type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onButtonClick()">Submit</button>

import { ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('submitButton') submitButton:ElementRef;

onButtonClick()
{
    this.submitButton.nativeElement.disabled = true;
    //Do some other stuff, maybe call a service etc...
    this.submitButton.nativeElement.disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution if you want to disable/enable button based on any other operation perform.

Answer (score 5):

You could use ngClass directive to deal with classes:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <div class=" uk-align-center" >
       <a [ngClass]="{'md-btn md-btn-success': !isButtonDisabled,
                      'md-btn disabled': isButtonDisabled }" 
          (click)="isButtonDisabled = !isButtonDisabled;">Start</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [
  `
  .md-btn md-btn-success {
    ...
  }
  .md-btn disabled {
    ...
  }
  `
 ]
})
export class App {
  isButtonDisabled: false;

  constructor() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

i'm using Angular2-RC2. This is how i use *ngIf, maybe it helps.
NOTE: in this example, once the button is pressed, it will be disabled, so you cannot click it to call the function unpushMe() anymore.

**text-area.component.ts**

```
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
    selector: 'textarea-comp',
    template: `
        <div>
          <div *ngIf="!isPushed" >
                <p><button (click)="pushMe()">push2disable</button></p>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="isPushed" >
                <p><button (click)="unPushMe()" disabled >disabled</button></p>
        </div>
    `
    })

    export class TextAreaComponent {
            isPushed: boolean = false;


    pushMe() {
            this.isPushed = true;
      }
        unPushMe() {
            this.isPushed = false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect , thanx :)